# git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory could not read Username for

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I think I have done a fair share of research into this issue, but I have not been able to find a corresponding problem/solution.

**What is trying to be achieved**

Publish and push a solution from VS 2017 to Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

**Reproduceable Example**

A new solution "GitExample" with the project "ExampleProject" has in been created (/w "Create new Git repository" checked).

In the Team Explorer window I select "Publish Git Repo" under the "Push to Visual  Studio Team Services" section. I choose my account and domain and press "Publish Repository".

Following error message is printed from Git.

```
Opening repositories:
c:\users\SampleUser\source\repos\PythonApplication4
Commit e3b04515 created locally in repository c:\users\SampleUser\source\repos\PythonApplication4
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
ArgumentNullException encountered.
   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
ArgumentNullException encountered.
   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
cannot spawn /C/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://repodomain.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://repodomain.visualstudio.com/_git/PythonApplication4

A new Git repository has been created for you in C:\Users\SampleUser\source\repos\GitExample.
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\SampleUser\source\repos\GitExample
Commit 5d8765b7 created locally in repository C:\Users\SampleUser\source\repos\GitExample
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\SampleUser\source\repos\GitExample
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
ArgumentNullException encountered.
   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
ArgumentNullException encountered.
   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
cannot spawn /C/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://repodomain.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://repodomain.visualstudio.com/_git/GitExample
```

The problem seems to reside with the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). However, the Windows Credential Manager correctly lists git:repodomain.visualstudio.com with the correct User Name and Password combination.

**What has been done:**

1. Uninstall git for Windows and reinstall without Windows Credential Manager. Install Windows Credential Manager from GitHub repo.

   2. Repair Visual Studio 2017 installation.
   3. Delete and create Login in Credential Manager

I appreciate your time and effort looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **check the connection to the VSTS accounts from your email address by Manage connection in Team explorer**. Detail steps as below:

In VS -> Team Explorer -> Manage Connections -> Connect to a project -> check if the you can connect to the VSTS account/domain (https://repodomain.visualstudio.com).

[image]
[image]

Besides, please also **check if you have permission to create new projects in the VSTS account https://repodomain.visualstudio.com**. Steps to check the permission as below:

In the VSTS account Security Page (https://repodomain.visualstudio.com/_settings/security) -> select the group you are in -> Check if the permission to create new projects is allowed.

[image]

Comment: Hello Marina Liu, Thank you for your support. Your hint at checking the connection with VSTS and the permission where not found to be the source of problems. I did however, manage to fix the problem. I have not posted an answer yet, as I am not sure which step solved the problem. Here is what I did: Uninstall every version of GIT (also the one provided with VS17). Modify VS17 installation without "Git for Windows". Install "Git for Windows" from website. Clone repo with command-line git. Authenticate. Now all git functionality was available within VS17.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error in Visual Studio 2019:

```
cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe
```

In my case the solution was different.  The issue was that the built-in git that comes with Visual Studio 2019 was not handing two-step authentication correctly.

The solution:

```
-First make sure you close all visual studio instances.
-Delete all generic credentials in windows credential manager related to git, devops, azure, SSO_POP_Device, virtualapp/didlogical, etc
-Delete the GitCredentialManager\\tenant.cache in the %appdata% folder
-Bring up the default web browser and open your repository.  In my case, I just had to open up the following site:

https://dev.azure.com/myDevOpsSite
```

This way you are prompted for user/password and then for a two step authentication verification on your phone.  After this, the credentials are stored correctly and you can now open visual studio and push/pull from within visual studio with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error in VS2019 by resetting the Git proxy:
Close VS.
Run CMD as administrator and execute this cmd:
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy:8080
Start VS